# Zend Studio: Tab display value and indentation size

Tags: zend-studio

Is it possible to set up the IDE so that the tab display value is 2 spaces, but the actual indentation size is 4 spaces?

I've tried setting the `Displayed tab width` to `2` under `General -> Editors -> Text Editors`

In `PHP -> Code Style -> Formatter` I have:

`Tab policy: Spaces`
`Indentation size: 4`

In `JavaScript -> Code Style -> Formatter` I have:

`Tab policy: Spaces only`
`Indentation size: 4`
`Tab size: 2`

I'd like it so that, when working in the IDE, indented code would appear as two spaces, ie:

```
function foo() 
{
..return 'Hello World!';
}
```

But the actual file would be indented with 4 spaces:

```
function foo() 
{
....return 'Hello World!';
}
```

Is it possible? Everything I've tried up to this point hasn't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this automatically Like the way u want.
You have to make profiles to make your work easier. Change your project setting to 4 spaces profile before saving.